# How to limit editText Length by using Different Language?

Tags: java, android

I want to limit editText length, If user type **English** in editText I want to limit 50 characters,
or If user Type a **Japan** language in editText I want to limit **30** characters, I want to achieve Multiple scenarios using one editText, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

**In Java**:

```
    public void filter(EditText editText) {
        String language = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        
     if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("English")) {
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
      } else if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("Japan")) {
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)});
      }
```

**In Kotlin:**

```
fun filter(editText: EditText) {
        val language = Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage
        if (language.equals("English", ignoreCase = true)) {
            editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(10))
        } else if (language.equals("Japan", ignoreCase = true)) {
            editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(20))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this scenario but no use,,is possible to achieve above scenarios by using textwatcher?,,if yes then how can i achieve

Comment: no possible using textwatcher. you should call above code in concrete() of the activity. I mean before text taping in edittext. when you switch locale this should be executed again

Comment: ok..currently i am using fragment..inside oncreateview method i added above code

Comment: did you debug whether it executed editText.setFilters() ?

Comment: no..editText.setFilters not executing for both cases

Comment: whats the local string you are gettig.? I mean ims.getLocale();

Comment: its printings as ja and is there any alternative method instead od editText.setFilter

Comment: Ok..but editText. setfilter not executing inside if..else block

Comment: I will check another alternative

Comment: updated answer. please check. Its working for English. Please find the language for japan and do it

Comment: I checked my last answer its working plz check and reply